# Wrong url in sortable column headers & pagination in the admin, when behind a proxy

Tags: admin, urls

Recently I changed the url of my site from atlas.site.com to site.com, one thing I just came across in the admin area for posts, custom post types, pages, where there are more than one page of posts, the arrows for next, previous, first & last page, are all pointing at atlas.site.com/wp-admin/...

I've done a find and replace for atlas in the db, but perhaps I'm not looking in the right place, and it returned 0 results, and WP_SITEURL & WP_HOME in wp-config are both set to http://www.site.com/

The same applies for Title, Author, Date at the top of the columns for sorting.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching?

Comment: nope not yet, site is still under development

Comment: What function are you using for your next/previous links?

Comment: This is just the untouched wordpress backend, not pagination on the front end, if that's where you were heading with your question.

Comment: For Wordpress, you don't need to hack the codebase at all. I found the fix from this answer to work great
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so apparently this site is behind a firewall or proxy.

On lines 491 and 658 in wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php, replace this line `$current_url = ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

with

`if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])){
    $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
} else {
    $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
$current_url = ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $hostname . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Thanks goes to http://www.stat.sinica.edu.tw/alvin/blog/archives/1129/ for posting this fix.

Now the question is there any way to do this without editing core files? If anyone can post that I'll mark that as the accepted answer, I haven't had to modify my core yet, and I'd prefer to keep it that way.

Comment: Please post your question about doing this w/o editing core as a new question and link back to here for context ... I definitely want to see how this can be done w/o hacking core ...

Comment: New question posted, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52801/4090

Answer (score 1):

Check Settings » General and make sure WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are both set properly.  Then go to Settings » Permalinks and reset your permalink structure.

Also, you should do a global find in your database, but not necessarily replace (although if you're doing a find/replace from `atlas.site.com` to `www.site.com` or `site.com` it should be safe).  Either way, back up your database before doing any global operations.

Edit: Okay, one more idea then I'm stumped.  Try the [Relocate Method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method) - add this line to `wp-config.php` before the "stop editing" line: `define('RELOCATE',true);`, go to `wp-login`, log in as normal, go to Settings->General, make sure both URL's are correct, save settings, then remove that line from `wp-config.php`.

Comment: WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL): Correct, Permalinks: Reset, Global Find: Found Nothing

Comment: So the word 'atlas' appears nowhere in any of your files and anywhere in your database?  That doesn't make any sense at all.  Try doing a SQL dump, load it into Notepad++, and do a find in there, or search using phpMyAdmin (use the `%` wildcard on either side of 'atlas').  It has to exist in one of those 2 places (files or database) to show up at all.

Comment: I realize it makes no sense, and it's driving me nuts, I just did a db dump, opened it in notepad, nothing. Downloaded the entire site locally, searched every file in each directory, found one instance of atlas, and was commented out in a css file. I'm stumped. I know it has to be coming from one of these places.

Comment: One more thing for you to try, then I'm out of ideas.  Updated my post to reflect.

Comment: This is blowing my mind, still no change.

Comment: This is beyond bizarre...

Comment: I'm currently trying to work backwards to figure out where exactly wp is pulling this url from, will update if I have any success, thanks for your attempts.

Comment: Still no luck, but a thought that might shed a little light on this, does wordpress set a url anywhere based on server name? The server the site sits on is still atlas.site.com

Answer (score 0):

Try a find/replace in the codebase. Whatever plugin is creating that custom post type may have hardcoded URLs to those assets/links.

Comment: Just searched, turned up nothing, I should have been less specific above, it actually happens for all posts & pages.