# Possible to fix admin URL behind proxy issue without hacking core?

Tags: core-modifications, proxy

In a [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52096/4090) I was trying to solve an issue where WordPress was using the wrong url in sortable column headers & pagination in the admin when behind a proxy, the only solution that worked involved modifying core files, specifically

On lines 491 and 658 in wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php, replace this line

`$current_url = ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

with

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
} else {
    $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
$current_url = ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $hostname . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Anyone know how to do this without modifying the core?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I threw this question around on Twitter and asked for feedback from some other core developers.  My gut instinct was to make `$current_url` either filterable or generated by a function that could be overridden.  This is, apparently, the wrong way about it.

> **[@markoheijnen](https://twitter.com/#!/markoheijnen):**
>   @EricMann Resetting `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` sounds like a hackish solution. Same code then can be in wp-config.php
>
> **[‏@nacin](https://twitter.com/#!/nacin):**
>   @EricMann @markoheijnen Putting it in wp-config is proper. It is not WP's job to handle reverse proxy situations.
>
> @EricMann @markoheijnen Ideally, they should be set properly before WP (or even PHP) is loaded. wp-config is the alternative.
>
> **[@markoheijnen](https://twitter.com/#!/markoheijnen):**
>   @nacin @ericmann In this case the server/proxy is wrong configured. So I can see why it then should be fixed in wp-config

From the sounds of this converation, you have two options:

1. Reconfigure your proxy to set the correct host values before things even get to PHP/WP.
2. Manually clean and set up `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in your `wp-config.php` file.

---

I thought a bit more, and here's some actual code you could add to `wp-config.php` to set things up (based on the hacky patch that changes core files):

```
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

This should set things up such that the default core files don't need any modification to function correctly.  But please note that I can't test this since I don't have any kind of proxy setup to verify it against ... so if this code *doesn't* help fix your situation, please report back and we can try something else.

Comment: Also see this, which might help:
http://wolfgang.reutz.at/2009/06/12/using-wordpress-with-a-proxy-webserver-in-front/

Comment: @EAMann your code suggestion above appears to be working, I'll be using that for now, fortunately our IT Dept is looking into fixing it on the server so that I won't have to do anything to fix it on my end. Thanks

Comment: Worked for my config, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue.  We were using Apache as the proxy (ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse defined) and the simple addition of the following to the virtual host resolved it:

Add to the virtual host:

ProxyPreserveHost on

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache httpd v2.4 I use the following to operate /wp-admin under a private apache instance  with no modifcation to any code or additions to wp-config.php.

Note: I had to obfuscate the example too much to get past the filter.  Hopefully the keywords are enough to get you started.

RequestHeader set Host yourdomain
Header edit* Location ^yourdomain privatedomain

SetOutputFilter Sed
OutputSed "s#yourdomain/#/#g"

My public apache instance  denies access to /wp-admin.

Comment: Please, [ask a new Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). We don't work like a forum, check this small guide: [About].